# how to Configure connection to backend dynamically in environment.prod.ts of Angular app?

Tags: angular, jhipster

Building an app which has the frontend developed in Angularjs and backend in Java(maven).

Below is the environment.prod.ts file for Angular communicate with backend.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  urlAddress: 'http://localhost:8085'
};
```

So far deployed the app locally, I start both frontend and backend as below and the app worked fine in local machine - localhost:4200

```
frontend 
ng server --host 0.0.0.0

backend
java -jar backend.jar
```

The problem occured when I tried to access the app from a different system in the same network. I can able to access the front end using the system deployed IP address like below instead of localhost:4200.

```
192.168.43.214:4200
```

But the connection to backend not working, when I did the browser inspect, found out it tries to access the localhost:8085 as backend because of the IP address localhost:8085 hardcoded in environment.prod.ts file.

When I tried to access the java backend service alone using system IP address, jhipster page coming and its working fine too.

```
192.168.43.214:8085
```

Configured prod file as below fixed the issue

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  urlAddress: 'http://192.168.43.214:8085'
};
```

But I have to know beforehand the IP address of the system where backend service going to run.

Since both frontend and backend going to run in the same server. How to make the angular to use its own IP address for backend connection.

Thanks,

Mohan

Comment: In production, you're not going to use ng serve, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: For learning purpose I am building that app , can the Ip address of angular used to hit java service? is any method like that available.

Comment: It's the reverse, you can access the angular app through the java port 8005 but then you don't get hot reloading for changes in frontend files. This is usually enough when you want to get other users to access the app running on your PC, the webpack proxy is useful only for yourself locally. By the way, it's not `ng serve` for JHipster it's `npm start` see https://www.jhipster.tech/development/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  urlAddress: 'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':8085'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The [angular website](https://angular.io/guide/build) goes into detail of how to configure environment files and have the system replace it when you build for different environment.